# using scss in vue only in a specific component not others

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

i am working on a vue project,
on a route for example /app there are components that not using scss.
and on another route for example /admin there are components that using scss.
when i import /app route and its childs in project it creates errors like this:

```
font-size: $font-size-base;
            ^
      Undefined variable: "$font-size-base".
```

when i remove /app and its child routes from router file errors will solve and works fine.
i imported scss in /admin parent component to only use scss in this route but it didnt solve the error.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using require to address an image file in one of my components. that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack needs to process SCSS when your project runs. You're seeing this on routes because things aren't rendered in Vue until they're called by either a route or a parent component.

Vue can use regular CSS and SASS together. You have to set it up to process the files though.

I'm assuming that you have CSS or SCSS in each template file

```
<template> ... </template>
<script> ... </script>
<style> CSS or SCSS rules </style>
```

In that case you need to tell Vue to preprocess the stuff inside the style tags. Do that with the `lang` attribute in the template where you have SCSS.

```
<style lang="SCSS"> ... </style>
```

You also need to include the [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) and [sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) packages.

---

**Note:** You need to define the SCSS variable `$font-size-base` in the component that uses it since by default each template is self-contained.

Comment: thanks for answer. scss works fine when i dont use components that not using scss. so it means node-sass and sass-loader working good. but when i import my only css style components in project it cause these errors.

Comment: does the component calling the SCSS variable actually have the definition in the same component?

Comment: yes i checked. all variables are defined and have value.

Comment: but they're defined in the SAME component that uses the value? Does the component that defines AND uses the variable have lang="scss"?

Comment: no they are defined in variables.scss file. all scss style components have lang="scss".

Comment: That's the problem then. You need to be importing that `variable.scss` file and making it globally available. Take a look at [style-resources-loader](https://github.com/yenshih/style-resources-loader) You'll also need to modify your Vue Config to point at the right resource.